# How can I declare a &[&T]] in rust?

Tags: vector, reference, rust

I have this code I cannot compile :

```
let vec1 = [1i, 2i, 3i];
let vec2 = [4i, 5i];
let v: &[&[int]] = [&vec1, &vec2];
```

What I want here is clear : I want to indicate v contains &[int] items, i.e. references to arrays of heterogenous sizes. But, no matter how I tag v's type, I get compiler errors. The above states

```
tst.rs:8:29: 8:34 error: mismatched types: expected `&[int, ..3]`, found `&[int, ..2]`     (expected array, found array)
tst.rs:8    let v: &[&[int]] = [&vec1, &vec2];
                                       ^~~~~
tst.rs:8:21: 8:35 error: mismatched types: expected `&[&[int]]`, found `[&[int, ..3], ..2]` (expected &-ptr, found array)
tst.rs:8    let v: &[&[int]] = [&vec1, &vec2];
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What is the solution here ?

Comment: you're just missing a `&`. `let v: &[&[int]] = &[&vec1, &vec2];` (note the & after the =) works. However, depending on how you plan to use v, you may run in trouble with lifetimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let vec1 = [1i, 2i, 3i];
let vec2 = [4i, 5i];
let v = [vec1.as_slice(), vec2.as_slice()];
let v: &[&[int]] = v.as_slice();
```

The first `v` is of type `[&[int], ..2]` and the second `v` is of type `&[&[int]]`. We can't define `v` of type `&[&[int]]` directly because we must define storage for the `[&[int], ..2]` before we can borrow it.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried the verbose `slice(0, vec1.len())` method but didn't know about `as_slice()`.

Comment: @Fabien : Note that with `#![feature(slicing_syntax)]`, `v[]` is equivalent to `v.as_slice()`.

Comment: @Levans: It might not stay, however isn't `&*v` equivalent?

Comment: @MatthieuM. It would be if `v` was a `Vec<T>`, but `[T,..N]` does not implement Deref.